# Valgrind LeakDefinetlyLost

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

i have encountered a valgrind problem within this C function. I would be glad if i recive some help, ty.

```
char* readHTTPRequestFile() {
    FILE *HTTPRequestTXT = fopen("HTTP-Request.txt", "r+");

    int lengthOfTXT = 0;
    while (fgetc(HTTPRequestTXT) != '\n') {
        lengthOfTXT += 1;
    }
    fseek(HTTPRequestTXT, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char* buffer = calloc(sizeof(char), lengthOfTXT);
    fgets(buffer, lengthOfTXT, HTTPRequestTXT);
    fclose(HTTPRequestTXT);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Whomever called this function needs to `free` the returned pointer, since it was allocated with `calloc` above. That's it. `char* buffer = calloc(sizeof(char), lengthOfTXT);` isn't going to magically clean itself up (and you wouldn't want it to). For future reference, questions about valgrind reports, error messages, warnings, etc, should include the actual reported text *verbatim* in the question, and the related code to said same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.